# Changing the value of a property in child component does not work

Tags: angular

Hi I have a situation where I would like to change the value of a property inside a component. Here is what I have so far:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {TinymceComponent} from './../../../common/components/tinymce.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'templates',
    directives: [TinymceComponent],
    template: `<button (click)="update()">Update</button> 
               <tinymce [(description)]="product.description"></tinymce>`
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {   
    public product: any;

    public ngOnInit() {
       this.product = {
           description: 'hello world'
       } 
    }

    public update(){
      console.log(this.product)
    }
}
```

And this is my TinyMceComponent:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';
declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'tinymce',
    template: '<textarea id="tinymce-editor"></textarea>',
})
export class TinymceComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() description: string;

    public ngOnInit() {      
        setTimeout(() => this.description = 'new text', 5000)
    }
}
```

What is happening at the moment is that the value of product.description remains as 'hello world' even after the setTimeout function get executed and sets description to 'new text'

What I would like to do is to be able to change the description property from the product model inside the TinyMceComponent. Now I am not sure if my approach is correct I assumed it would work because something like this used to work in angular 1 but I might be wrong.

Can anyone tell me how I would achieve this?

Comment: You are not using description in TinymceComponent's template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9ds4H?p=preview) shows `hello world` and that changes to `new text` after 5 seconds.

for one-way-binding (parent-to-child) only `[description]` is enough

```
[(description)]="product.description"
```

is for two-way binding and would require a

```
@Output() descriptionChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

in `TinymceComponent`

Comment: That is true but if you pres update  and open the console you will see that the product object still prints 'hello world' instead of 'new text' that is my problem the product model does not get updated.... I might be missing something here or my approach is not the right one for what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

You should be using only square braces, because you've only defined an `input` property. Your component doesn't seem to emit any events. So your template should look like this:

```
<button (click)="update()">Update</button> 
<tinymce [description]="product.description"></tinymce>
```

The square brackets `[]` are for `@Input` properties and the parantheses `()` are for `@Output` properties.

Answer (score 2):

**[working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/f1Al73cAtVc7cc5kGDpC?p=preview)**

```
import {Component, Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Output() descriptionChange:EventEmitter= new EventEmitter()

ngOnInit() {      
        //setTimeout(() => this.description = 'new text', 5000)
       this.descriptionChange.emit("new Text");
}
```